# Solving ODE by series solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm losing my mind and really stressing out here. So I would like to ask some help please.

I'm trying to solve this ODE by using a series (as required).
$$x^2y''+5xy'+(4-x)y=0$$

I know that there is a regular singluar point at x=0
The indicial equation is $m^2+4m+4=0$ So $m=-2$ is a root, with multiplicity 2.

So we let 
$$y=x^{-2}\sum_0^\infty{a_n}x^n=\sum_0^\infty{a_n}x^{n-2}$$
$$y'=\sum_0^\infty{a_n}(n-2)x^{n-3}$$
$$y''=\sum_0^\infty{a_n}(n-2)(n-3)x^{n-4}$$

So subbing back into the ODE we get 
$$\sum_0^\infty{a_n}(n-2)(n-3)x^{n-2}+5\sum_0^\infty{a_n}(n-2)x^{n-2}+4\sum_0^\infty{a_n}x^{n-2}-\sum_0^\infty{a_n}x^{n-1}=0$$

I've been trying to solve this equation (and another at the same time) and everytime I try anything from any ODE I work with I always obtain all $a_n=0$.

For instance,we solve for the $x^{-2}$ term and obtain
$$a_0(-2)(-3)+5(-2)a_0+4a_0=0\implies{a_0}=0$$

From here we get $a_1$ in terms of $a_0$. But that is 0 and there are no stray constant terms. Thus $a_1=0$, and the vicious cycle continues. I know this is wrong, but I cannot even solve for $y_1$ let alone try to find $y_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Try:
$$
y(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n
$$
Then:
\begin{align}
y' &= \sum_{n \ge 0} n a_n x^{n - 1}
    = \sum_{n \ge 0} (n + 1) a_{n + 1} x^n \\
y'' &= \sum_{n \ge 0} n (n - 1) a_n x^{n - 2}
    = \sum_{n \ge 0} (n + 2) (n + 1) a_{n + 2} x^n
\end{align}
Substituting into your equation:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} n (n - 1) a_n x^n
  &+ 5 \sum_{n \ge 0} n a_n x^n
  + 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n
  - 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^{n + 1}
  = 0 \\
(n (n - 1) + 5 n + 4) a_n
  &= 4 a_{n - 1} \quad \text{for $n \ge 1$} \\
(n^2 + 6 n + 9) a_{n + 1}
  &= a_n \quad \text{$a_0$ arbitrary}
\end{align}